# how do i input some string and store it in a variable ? (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

i want the equivalent of this C# piece of code in C++

```
String name;
name=Console.ReadLine();
```

i tried the following code, but its not working!

```
struct node{string player_name};
    p=new struct node;
    getline(cin,p->player_name);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Is there some reason you don't use `std::string name; std::getline(std::cin, name);`?

Comment: i declared using namespace std;

Comment: i don't get any errors ,it just doesn't ask me to input anything!

Comment: try to get a basic C++ book, here is a list http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3093378

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s;
    getline(cin,s);
    cout << s;
}
```

Try it here at http://ideone.com/AgLUGv

Comment: Explaining a bit further: this is the best way in C++ to achieve the same intent as the Java code, lacking any further context. The Java version uses a different memory management strategy which we could emulate in C++ if we wanted to; however we don't want to because C++ has more memory management options available and this code shows the best one for the job.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't compile. It is missing a `;` after `player_name`, for example. Here is a version that does compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct node{
    std::string player_name;
};

int main()
{
   node * p= new node();
   std::getline(std::cin, p->player_name);
   delete p;
   return 0;
}
```

Of course there is a simpler way of doing this, you do not need to use `new/delete` you can create the object on the stack. The contents of `player_name` are created in the heap:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct node {
    std::string player_name;
};

int main()
{
    node p;
    std::getline( std::cin, p.player_name);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want the equivalent of your `C#` code, then we can remove the `node struct`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::getline( std::cin, name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're forgetting `#include <string>`. Your code may compile, because many compilers will automatically include the `string` library when you `#include <iostream>` but that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: Just because it compiles doesn't mean it's right. For instance, why are you allocating dynamically?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Being "right" is a matter of opinion. The reason why I allocate dynamically is because the asker was allocating it dynamically. of course it is better use a `std::string` object, but by doing two things at the same time, the asker doesn't have the chance to learn something.